# What is Esri's support plan for Python 2.7 beyond 2020 for ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcpy, python-2.7, arcgis-10.6

According to **[PEP-373](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0373/)**, Python 2.7 will retire on January 1, 2020 ([Countdown Clock](https://pythonclock.org/)). That date was pushed back 5 years for those who couldn't migrate to Python 3.

According to this [**product life cycle page**](https://support.esri.com/en/Products/Desktop/arcgis-desktop/arcmap/10-6-1#product-support) for ArcGIS Desktop, 10.6.1 will retire 4 years later on January 1, 2024. Sure, ArcGIS Pro supports Python 3, but there will be a gap of unsupported Python for those still using Desktop leading up to its retirement.

[**Esri's Deprecation Plan for 10.6**](http://downloads.esri.com/Support/downloads/other_/DEPRECATED%20FEATURES%20PLAN%20FOR%20ARCGIS%2010.6%20and%20ArcGIS%20Runtime%20SDK%20100.x%20Year-end%202017%20v1.pdf) makes no mention of Python support beyond 2020.

I know that Python 2.7 is pretty stable, but I wonder, what are Esri's plans for support during this time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I will of course defer to anyone from Esri on this, but my feeling is that in terms of Python support Esri only supports its own ArcPy and Python API for ArcGIS modules.

Even though ArcGIS Desktop ships with a copy of Python and various third party Python libraries like numpy, etc, I would expect that a bug found in any of them would not obligate Esri to try and fix Python or a third party Python library now or at any time in the future.

On the other hand I would expect that Esri will continue to make its best efforts to fix any bugs found in ArcPy for ArcGIS Desktop 10.6 up until it enters Mature Support in January 2022 *using the version of Python as shipped with ArcGIS Desktop 10.6*.

From https://twitter.com/Esri/status/976105503288774656 it looks like 10.7 is underway so if new dot releases of ArcGIS Desktop 10.x ship beyond Python 2.x's sunset on 1 January 2020, then I think they would just continue to use the latest version of Python 2.x that had shipped with an earlier dot release, as long as that version of Python 2.x continues to work on any [certified Operating System versions](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/system-requirements/latest/arcgis-desktop-system-requirements.htm#GUID-0D22816B-298C-4ABF-BC4E-5C32D605F055).

---

An update from Esri in a blog post titled [How sunsetting Python 2 affects ArcGIS](https://www.esri.com/arcgis-blog/products/arcgis/announcements/how-sunsetting-python-2-affects-arcgis/) says:

> First thing to note: All the Python 2.7 code in ArcGIS will continue
>   to work. Also, Esri will continue to support Python 2.7 in ArcMap,
>   ArcCatalog, ArcMap extensions (including ArcScene and ArcGlobe, which
>   are part of the ArcGIS 3D Analyst extension), ArcGIS Engine, and
>   ArcGIS Server.
>
> ...
>
> **Is there a plan to move ArcMap to a supported version of Python (e.g., Python 3.x)?**
>
> No. However, with the ArcGIS 10.8 release, we are upgrading to the
>   latest Python 2.7.x libraries available (currently 2.7.16). We also
>   have plans to upgrade ArcMap to the 2.7.17 libraries when they are
>   available.
>
> …
>
> **How long will Esri continue to support Python 2.7?**
>
> Esri will continue
>   to support Python 2.7 in accordance with the relevant Product Life
>   Cycles